# Some questions on character encoding in http request from JavaScript to Java

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, http, character-encoding

I found some corrupted string data in our database (Sybase ASE 15.7) that would suggest a wrong encoding was inserted (the data was truncated at 1260 characters even though the field is VARCHAR(2000))

The data was being sent like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: constructUrl(url),
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
  data: data
})...
```

The data was text data, all using English characters and numbers, in standard JSON format, sent from China via Chrome browser to a DB in London.

Is it possible that in China the default character set in Chrome is something other than UTF-8 (say UTF-16)?

If so, would it help if I change the header to

```
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
```

(adding the UTF-8), or is that the default anyway?

The application has other requests as well, with content type = application/text. Would appending the charset=UTF-8 help there as well?

Comment: 1) application/x-www-form-urlencoded doesn't take a charset parameter. 2)  application/text does. -- that said, this is very hard to analyze without something more concrete to look at.

Comment: What else would help?

Comment: Then does application/x-www-form-urlencoded assume string data is UTF-8?

Comment: No, thee payload of a application/x-www-form-urlencoded message is plain ASCII. Characters are encoded/escaped *before* placing them into the payload. The gory details are in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: So my issue might be something else then. Plain ASCII is always going to be 8 bit, which would not account for the truncation

Comment: This may sound silly, but: What is the collation of the `VARCHAR` field? It would also hellp if you could specify the RDBMS in use. If it happens to be MySQL, you may want to check the documentation on [row size limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits).

Comment: @DaSourcerer - that's a good point

Comment: Sybase ASE 15.7

Comment: Well, it seems that `VARCHAR(2000)` can hold up to 2,000 *bytes*. Using `NVARCHAR(2000)` instead could solve the problem.